# Certificate Authority Trust/Validation Hierarchy

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority

I have 2 Private CAs at the moment, one Root CA and a Subordinate CA. The Subordinate CA's CSR is signed by the Root CA. We have apps that would be using the Subordinate CA to do mutual TLS authentication.

Question: I have existing certificates that have been signed by the Root CA, can that be used in conjunction with the Subordinate CA? Or do I have to create new certificates that are signed by the Subordinate CA in order for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The certificates signed by the root CA are trusted. It is the nature of PKI. If you place RootCA's certificated into CA store, then all certificates signed by that certifcate will be valid. Still ...

Typically it is considered unwise to sign end-users certificates with the root. It is a long-lasting certificate that serves as the cornerstone of the whole infrastructure. In your place I would consider unifying PKI and re-issue the end-users' and servers' certificates using the intermediate CA.